# change parse.com class with UISwitch in queryForTable()

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I have trying to switch between the parse class using a UISwitch . 
I have two classes mainClass and recentClass in parse , I'm trying to switch between them by using the syntax .

I have already declared the query 
on the top of the class like this.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var barSwitch: UISwitch!

 var query =  PFQuery(className: "mainClass")  


 func switchChanged(barSwitch:UISwitch){

    if (barSwitch.on == true) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in

          self.query = PFQuery(className: "recentClass")

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    ) }
        else   {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in

            self.query = PFQuery(className: "mainClass")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("button was pressed")

            }
        ) }

    }
```

I have no idea how I can use that switch in my queryForTable()

```
 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {


    if (objects?.count == 0)
    {

        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork


    }
    query.orderByAscending("SNo")

    return query
}
```

As per @Tim I have edited but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-declaring `query` inside the switch function, so it's not changing your class variable. Take out `let` and `var` in front of `query` in the func.

Also, inside a `dispatch`, you probably need to put `self.query`.

To call the `switchChanged` func in `queryForTable`:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    switchChanged(barSwitch)

    if (objects?.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    }
    query.orderByAscending("SNo")

    return query
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? I added a comment in the answer.

Comment: When you say it's "not working" what does that mean? Does it always stay on the `mainClass`, or are you getting an error?

Comment: data from mainClass is displaying only.

Comment: updated. Of course, you could also use an @IBAction func instead to set the `query`.

Comment: how can i use it . I'm not getting it

Comment: switchChanged(barSwitch) was added to the `queryForTable`.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I'm a new developer so no idea how can I solve the issue.